# How to optimize the performance of a `pandas` `DataFrame` using `numexpr` and `Dask`?

Tags: python, pandas, dask-dataframe, numexpr

I'm working with a large `pandas` `DataFrame` and I'm trying to optimize its performance using the `numexpr` and `Dask` libraries. I've tried using the `numexpr.evaluate()` function to perform element-wise operations on the DataFrame, but it's still taking a long time to run.

Here's an example of the code I'm using:

```
import numexpr
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('large_data.csv')

# Perform element-wise operation using numexpr
df['new_column'] = numexpr.evaluate('df.column1 + df.column2')
```

Is there a way to further optimize the performance of this code using `Dask` or some other method?